# force early renewal of PayPal sandbox subscription

Tags: php, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am testing PayPal's subscription process by using PayPal's sandbox, but the thing is, the minimum period is 1 days, and I want to perform multiple tests until I get everything right, I surely do not need to wait for a period of 1 day to test my code changes.

So there surely should be a way for me to trigger subscription renewal, or some way to work around it.

I've tried to set subscription period to 0.01 days, and PayPal would not accept that. So any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: **Related:** https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/testing-subscription-renewal-payments/ (possibly)

Comment: Nope, you're locked in.

Comment: @Script47 ***if you are using PayPal or WorldPay, this process will not work and you must wait until the payment gateway processes the renewal*** apparently there is no solution for this, as stated on the link you sent.

Comment: @AL-Kateb that must be the answer then.