# How to test upcoming recurring subscription payment in Paypal

Tags: stripe-payments, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I have subscription based recurring payments on my website using Paypal.
User is charged successfully on first subscription. How can I test if my subscription payment will be deducted successfully after one month?

Do I have to wait for one month to see what happens next?

How can I test it?

This is very simple in Stripe using test clock feature.Any similar feature exists in Paypal?

I am expecting to deduct my subscription payment using any button or any URL so that I can complete my development in sandbox environment.

Comment: Searching for "test paypal subscription" turns up other questions here already, the consensus seems to be to use a subscription period of 1 day, and that you can't do better than that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948866/force-early-renewal-of-paypal-sandbox-subscription, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499228/testing-recurring-payments-in-paypal-sandbox, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212090/testing-recurring-payments-in-the-paypal-sandbox, ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a subscription plan in sandbox with a cycle period of 1 day.